# File Path with the file name as a variable

Tags: unicode, path, extension-methods

I have a code that selects a zip folder from a path.  My problem is the zip folder name will always be different.  The path will always be the same though.

Example:  "C\Users\name\Customer\New_Archive_022820186S12.zip"

I would like to make the zip folder as a variable so any zip folder will be picked up regardless of the name.  In the example above the folder name is New_Archive_022820186S12.zip

What I'm looking for is a path name where the zip folder in the path is a variable

Suggestions?

Hi in C++ language.  Thanks so much

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: C+ is not a programming language. Do you mean C or C++?

Comment: apologies correct C++

Comment: Hi,
Apologies I have an error in my presentation.

My process is to unzip zip folders in this primary directory "C\Users\name\Customer\New_Archive_022820186S12.zip"
The folder name, in this example "New_Archive_022820186S12" will always change names. Wondering what I can insert in it's place for my unzip process to be able to pick up any folder in this path?

Thanks so much

Comment: Open the directory and look for names that match a pattern, if there's a pattern to match.

Comment: Hi tadman the one unique pattern is New_Archive in the folder name,
wondering what the path name would be using this?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store the folder path and filename in separate variables, and then you can concatenate them together when needed eg:

```
std::string folder = "C:\\Users\\name\\Customer\\";

std::string filename = "New_Archive_022820186S12.zip"; // <-- populate as needed...

std::string zipfile = folder + filename;
// use zipfile as needed...
```

Comment: A few words of explanation might make this more useful.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.